# Get html link id in django views.py

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

This is what my template `index.html` looks like

```html
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia 
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<h1>All Pages</h1>

<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'link' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my `urls.py` file

```py
path("link", views.link, name="link")
```

Finally, this is my `link` view inside of the `views.py` file

```py
def link(request, id):
    return redirect("page", name=id)
```

Where `page()` is a function that takes one argument. I want the `id` of the `<a></a>` tag of `index.html` to be that argument. But I have no idea how to access get that id inside of `views.py` when the `<a></a>` tag is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your statement with this line inside `index.html`.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'link' entry.id %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
```

Your `urls.py` should contain

```
path("link/<int:id>", views.link, name="link")
```

Now, you should get the id in the `id` variable of the `views.py` when the  tag is clicked.

Comment: It didn't work with the exact code you provided but with a few changes it's now functional. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help. What changes have you made?

Comment: `index.html` contains `<li><a href="{% url 'link' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>` and `views.py` contains `path("link/<str:title>", views.link, name="link")`